# Undefined reference (in some cases)

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, apa6

At first I would like to thank the community for the work that is done here. Whenever there is a LaTeX problem evolving, this site is the first to check by. However, this time it seems that no one has had my problem before (something truely unimageanable to me):

I am currently writing my thesis with LaTeX and the documentclass apa6. Whenever I try to refrence a section/ subsection/ ... I am not able to reference the section number with `\ref` or `\autoref`. However, it works with `\nameref`.

The Log throws "undefined references" errors for the first two references (i.e. `\ref` & `\autoref`) but not for the last.

Here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[man, 12pt, a4paper, floatsintext]{apa6}

%================ Packages =================================
% fontenc Package
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Lade Unicode 8
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Lade Neue Deutsche Rechtschreibung 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%url Package
\usepackage{url}

%Euro Zeichen
\usepackage{eurosym}

% todo=Package
\usepackage{todonotes}

% TikZ
\usepackage{tikz}

% Figure Packages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}

% um \patchcmd ausführen zu können
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Für gewisse Textzeichen
\usepackage{textcomp}

% Erleichterter Import von Dateien
\usepackage{import}

% Über- und Unterschriften für Bilter/ Tabellen
\usepackage{caption}

%Verbesserte Referenzen
\usepackage{hyperref}
% Hyperlinks weniger awkward
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
%Standalone
%\usepackage{standalone}

% apacite separat laden
\usepackage{apacite}

\title{Example of a Title}
\shorttitle{Short Example}
\author{Knows not}
\affiliation{XY}
\abstract{}


\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \section{Foo}
    \label{sec:foo}

    Referencing \ref{sec:foo} or \autoref{sec:foo}, that goes by the name of \nameref{sec:foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Nice MWE! However, it should be `\ref{sec:foo}`, not `\ref{section}`. Apparently the sections are unnumbered.

Comment: As "Foo" does not have a number, only `\nameref{sec:foo}` makes sense. `\ref{section}` cannot work, as you did not specify a label called`section`.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Of course it should have been `\ref{sec:foo}`. I edited that. However, the outcome is the same.

Comment: @gaspode It seems a precise choice of `apa6` not to number sections. Since `\ref` would print the number, it finds nothing.

Comment: @samcarter How would I add a number to make this MWE work? In fact, this is the core of the question.

Comment: @gaspode To get numbered section, use another document class. From the `apa6` documentation: "Please note that sections cannot be \ref’d since APA style does not use num- bered sections. So \label commands are unnecessary unless you wish to use \refname."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `apa6` style sections are not numbered. If you want to submit a paper to a journal that requires `apa6`, you should stick to the style.

Since the `man` style is among the worst I know from a typographic point of view, I wouldn't recommend using it for any purpose other than submissions.

Anyway, if you still want to use it and to number sections, add

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
```

after `\maketitle`.

Comment: Perfect, that did it! 

I know, the `man` style is a sheer beauty. But unfortunately, I have to write my thesis in the APA manual style...

Thank you, anyway!